# how to pass system properties to Java applet launched from HTML

Tags: java, applet, properties, system

Here is my applet:

```
<applet id="MyApplet" 
    code="com.my.MyApplet"
    archive="my.jar"
    myscript>
</applet>
```

How would one pass "-D" properties to this applet (similar to 'java -Dprop=val ... ' from a java launcher) ? I would like to pass some java security properties for this applet when launched.

Answer (score 10):

You can use a special param to pass -D values to Applets.

```
<param name="java_arguments" value="-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true">
```

You can find the documentation [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/applet/applet_deployment.html)

Answer (score -2):

include `param` tags inside your applet tag:

```
<param name="flavor" value="strawberry">
```